# How can I check if the Android Market is installed on my user's device?

Tags: android, google-play

How could I write a code which can tell me that android market is installed on your android phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways. You can use the already mentioned `getPackageManager()` and `getApplicationInfo()` (if the package is not found, a `PacketManager.NameNotFoundException` will be thrown - see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)). Android Market's package name is `com.android.vending`.

However, you can also create a dummy intent for searching the market and check how it is handled. If the resulting list has at least one entry, you can be sure that Android Market is installed:

```
Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=dummy"));
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = manager.queryIntentActivities(mmarket, 0);
```

Comment: Is "com.android.vending" also the packageName on Honeycomb (or later) devices where the "MyApps" application is used? Also, the "market://" intent check is unreliable because other market apps also use that.

Comment: I cannot say for sure when it comes to com.android.vending and Honeycomb. However, Android Developers refer to com.android.vending without any Honeycomb-specific notes (e.g.: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html), so I'd assume it works as expected.

Comment: On the Kindle Fire, Amazon's App Store will response to the market:// URIs.

Comment: @BrianPellin Do u mean that when I pass the intent with market:// URI, amazon device can still handle it and forward user to Amazon App Store? I know that I cannot upload to Amazon app store if I do so, but what if I don't care about this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (assumes browser exists):

```
Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri
        .parse("market://details?id=com.example.app"));


Intent website = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri
        .parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app"));

try {

    startActivity(market);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    startActivity(website);

}
```