# In-App Billing - What to do when the Play Store app is not installed?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, billing

I am going to be supporting In-App billing/ purchases in my app.

From what I have read, it seems the Play Store app must be installed on the device in order to do In-App billing. I have 2 Android devices for testing. Both are missing the Play Store app. I am sure this situation will exist for users of my app.

Question: What does an Android developer do when their app supports In-App billing but the Play Store app is not installed on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do a market payment if they do not have the market.

You could see if the market is [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482036/how-can-i-check-if-the-android-market-is-installed-on-my-users-device) and if not, either provide a clear message saying so, possibly with instructions on how to get it, or link to some other payment method like paypal in a web browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stefan. I was looking for this info on stackoverflow but did not find it. Thank you for pointing me to it.