# Is there a way to know in code from where the application downloaded on Android

Tags: android

I need to know how can I know from where to application apk downloaded from so I can make layout changes according to the download source?

Is there a way knowing it?

Comment: Besides making different APK's for different sources I don't think it's possible. Not in a way that's meant to be used for that objective anyway.

Comment: I heard about INSTALL_REFERRER, does it good for me?

Comment: What different markets are you releasing your app to where you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot get from the android system where the APK is downloaded from.

But you could use different signatures for different sources and do as I explained here:
[Supporting Amazon and Android market (Google Play) links inside application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480235/supporting-amazon-and-android-market-links-inside-application/7682815#7682815)

What I explain in the above question is specific to an app for amazon and an app for Android Market, but the same approach applies - as far as checking signatures and things.

Comment: I don't see INSTALL_REFERRER in the official documentation, so it is not a viable solution. And regardless, if you downloaded the app from an email or website or whatever - or if it were moved from computer to their SD card, the only thing that Android would possibly be able to tell you is that the install happened from a file on the sdcard, or that it was installed with the market app. But INSTALL_REFERRER still is not something that should be used because it is not in the official docs from what I could find.

Comment: see http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html#referrals

Comment: It may show you what installed it - Market/built in installer/etc but there is no way that it would be able to track where it was actually downloaded from because that information is not on the .apk file that was downloaded unless you hardcoded it prior to the download.