# How to manage 2 versions of an app free and registered?

Tags: android

I am fairly new at this, need inputs on how to manage a free version and a registered version 
Few thoughts
(a) Manage 1 git and two branches free and paid
(b) Manage a single version and differentiate by having a hidden setting in preferences

With (a) after user downloads the free version, upgrading would make 2 apps on the phone.
This is the problem.

With (b) I dont know how to download just the settings file

Is there any other way (c) ? as both are not working for me....

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing a library project:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Keep all the common code between your applications in that library:

Example: For your free and paid app, you can simply create a string with a default implementation (free version) and override it in your paid version (parent app).

Code in shared libraries Strings.xml file:

```
<string name="AppName">My Application (Free with ads)</string>
```

Code in parent app Strings.xml file:

```
<string name="AppName">My Application Premium</string>
```

So if you want to try this.. [This link will help you out](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

For more info:

[Multiple Apps with a shared code base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515230/multiple-apps-with-a-shared-code-base)

Comment: I am getting the essence but there are a few questions which I am not able to answer Paid app would be com.mycomp.paid and Free would be com.mycomp.free. Both would be there on store. Now how would com.mycomp.free be removed from the device when com.mycomp.paid is installed. ?